# Added id/class removed on update

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a simple class/id on my `<li>` element which is in my menu, by using jquery.

However, when I click on a menu-option my class/id is added by jquery successfully but my site of course is gonna update because it redirects to the choicen site.

The result I end up with is that my class/id is removed because of this update..

How can I bypass this so my class/id stays on the selected menu `<li>` element.

My code looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function()  
 {  
    $('li').click(function()  
    {  
       $(this).addClass('selected');  
    });  
 });
```

This is the site: http://insatsplutonen.xedge.nu/ 
Click yourself thru the menu-options. If you click on ex: Blogg the class 'selected will be added on the `<li>` element but will disappear because of page-load...

Thing is i want selected menu-option to turn white and others stay gray :)

Kind regards /Haris

Comment: Need a little more context. Are you actually navigating to another page?

Comment: You can only 'bypass' this behavior by using AJAX rather than posting back to the server. The easy way would be to leverage your server-side technology to add that class dynamically when needed.

Comment: The keyword is local storage ?

Comment: You could also use some kind of storage in between pages and then reload the data

Comment: So the `selected` class should be applied to the *new* page?

Comment: you don't need local storage or ajax. see my answer

Comment: What server-side programming language are you using? php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are loading the page based on the query string. When I select "Blogg", I get http://insatsplutonen.xedge.nu/?Blogg

When you load the page and check your query string and find a menu variable there, set a variable to the menu item value, and use it to set the class for the menu item accordingly. Ex. for Blogg item:

```
<li <?php echo ($queryStrVal == 'Blogg') ? 'class="selected"' : ''; ?>>
```

Comment: Thank you, now its solved :) Don't like it but still big thanks, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, one way to solve this is to have a page class, for example on the body, that you use to identify which menu option is currently "selected". So something like this:

```
<body class="home">
    <ul>
        <li id="homeNav"></li>
        <li id="aboutNav"></li>
        <li id="contactNav"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

then your css looks like this:

```
.home #homeNav,
.about #aboutNav,
.contact #contactNav {
    // whatever styles represent "selected" here
}
```

This way, the "selected" nav item always appears selected on the page it represents.

Answer (score 0):

To do in jQuery, find the `<a>` with the href of the window location and give its parent, which is `li` that class. This is happening once they reach the page they wanted, not when they click the link, so even pasting the URL in the browser add `.selected` to the correct `li`

```
var urlend= window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname, '');
$('a[href="' + urlend + '"]').parent().addClass("selected");
```

Comment: I changed it to this but still selected tag adds, but on redirect it is gone :(

Comment: Have you implemented the JS correctly because this happens on page load, not click of a link. Answer edited

Comment: ah, your links aren't full links so the the domain needs removing from window.location.href...